# How long does a reference remain valid after the object it references is dropped?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm reading [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) to figure out how lifetime works, one of the example (posted below) really shocked me,
I can't convince myself why `byte_1` and `byte_2` still live well after the `std::mem::drop(bytes);` is executed.

From my point of view, the references which `byte_1` and `byte_2` hold should be invalid after the iterator `bytes` is dropped because the `remainder` array is dropped as well, the compiler should treat the `drop` action as an error, but in fact it pass the compiler and runs without problem...

Hope someone can give a reasonable explanation for a programmer coming from C++/C#, thanks!

```
struct ByteIter<'remainder> {
    remainder: &'remainder [u8]
}

impl<'remainder> ByteIter<'remainder> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'remainder u8> {
        if self.remainder.is_empty() {
            None
        } else {
            let byte = &self.remainder[0];
            self.remainder = &self.remainder[1..];
            Some(byte)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bytes = ByteIter { remainder: b"1123" };
    let byte_1 = bytes.next();
    let byte_2 = bytes.next();
    std::mem::drop(bytes); // we can even drop the iterator now!
    if byte_1 == byte_2 { // compiles
        // do something
    }
}
```

(I've been learning Rust for a month, but still confused by lots of new concepts)

Comment: "the remainder array is dropped as well" - why should it be? You're not storing the array itself inside the `ByteIter`, you're only referencing it.

Comment: @Cerberus your words helped me notice the iterator returns an `Option<**&**u8>`, also a reference. The underlying array is still referenced by `byte1` and `byte2`, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to understanding why this works is looking at the way `Iterator` is defined:

```rust
trait Iterator{
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self)-> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

Notice how the lifetime of the return value has no connection to the lifetime of the `Iterator` itself. This means that the returned item must be able to live without the original `Iterator`. In this case, the indexing operation reborrows the original object that was borrowed for the same length of time as the borrow by the iterator*. This means that so long as you don't try to drop the underlying data you're borrowing from while the values returned by `Iterator::next` are in scope, the compiler will not throw an error. In your example, that can't happen because the thing you're iterating over is embedded in the binary itself. In a circumstance that you can drop the underlying data, [it results in a compiler error if you try.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0c6fd6709239d079e41c57d6152ca2e)

*This means the anti-aliasing rules require the use of unsafe code in many iterators returning mutable references.

Comment: I played with the example referenced in the answer, the compiler really knows who borrowed the byte array, that was impressive!

Comment: @YuWea Yep, it is awesome- the borrow checker is probably responsible for 80% of rust's memory safety guarantees.

Answer (score 7):

`bytes` does not own `b"1123"`. It only has a reference to it. Because there is no ownership, dropping `bytes` doesn't drop `b"1123"`. Dropping `bytes`'s reference doesn't affect other references with the same lifetime.

Now you could invalidate `byte_1` and `byte_2` if you were somehow able to drop the referent `b"1123"`. But that's impossible. `b"1123"` has a `'static` lifetime, and `'static` objects can't be dropped.

Comment: While this is true, this seems to focus too much on `'static`. The code also works with a non-`'static` lifetime: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d63165ef213ffd80780cdf17995972c4